# Urllib bad request issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.4, urllib, bad-request

I tried every `'User-Agent'` in [here](http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/change-urllib-user-agent/), still I get `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894320/again-urllib-error-httperror-http-error-400-bad-request), but I get `urllib.error.URLError: File Not Found`. I have no idea what to do, my current codes are;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request,json,ast

with open ("urller.json") as f:
    cc = json.load(f) #the file I get links, you can try this link instead of this
    #cc = ../games/index.php?g_id=23521&game=0RBITALIS 

for x in ast.literal_eval(cc): #cc is a str(list) so I have to convert
    if x.startswith("../"):

        r = urllib.request.Request("http://www.game-debate.com{}".format(x[2::]),headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})
        #x[2::] because I removed '../' parts from urlls

        rr = urllib.request.urlopen(r).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rr)

        for y in soup.find_all("ul",attrs={'class':['devDefSysReqList']}):
            print (y.text)
```

**Edit**: If you try only 1 link probably it won't show any error, since I get the error every time at 6th link.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `urllib`? I just tried `requests.get("http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=23521&game=0RBITALIS")` and it works perfectly. `requests` is far superior in virtually every respect.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan but I edited the question, if you try only 1 link probably it will be ok since I get that bad request error every time at 6th link from json file

Comment: Have you tried printing each URL before making the request?  Perhaps the URL is malformed in some obvious way.

Comment: @JohnGordon the link that I get the error is `../games/index.php?g_id=23255&game=12 Labours of Hercules II: The Cretan Bull`

Comment: Those embedded spaces may be causing the issue.  I don't believe literal spaces are allowed in a URL.

Comment: I thought that, but there are 3 links before this one and all of them have spaces. I'm really confused I'm not usually work with bs and urllib and this nonsense error is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to replace the space with `+`:

```
url = "http://www.game-debate.com"
r = urllib.request.Request(url + x[2:] ,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})
```

A better option may be to let urllib [quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) the params:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request,json,ast
from urllib.parse import quote, urljoin

with open ("urller.json") as f:
    cc = json.load(f) #the file I get links, you can try this link instead of this
    url = "http://www.game-debate.com"


    for x in ast.literal_eval(cc):  # cc is a str(list) so I have to convert
        if x.startswith("../"):
            r = urllib.request.Request(urljoin(url, quote(x.lstrip("."))), headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'})

            rr = urllib.request.urlopen(r).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rr)
            print(rr.decode("utf-8"))

            for y in soup.find_all("ul", attrs={'class':['devDefSysReqList']}):
                print (y.text)
```

Spaces in a url are not valid and need to be percent encoded as `%20` or replaced with `+`.